# Communication between two fragments with interface

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, fragment-lifecycle

My app have one activity A and two fragments F1 and F2.

One clicking button in F1, the F1 is replaced by F2.
I want to transfer data in F1 to F2. For that I implemented the interface in F1 and override its method in A.

But when sending the data from A to F2, my reference(***sFragment in code A***) to the F2 remains null,due to which data is not sent to F2. I am getting reference to the F2 using TAG provided while  replacing F1 by F2.

Does it have something to do with the lifecycle like when I am trying to get reference to the F2 it hasn't yet created?

**F1**

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.form_fragment1,container,false); 
    nextB = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.f1Next);
    nextB.setOnClickListener(this);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){

        case R.id.f1Next:
            SFragment fragment = new SFragment();
            FragmentManager mManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction mTransaction = mManager.beginTransaction();
            mTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment,"SecondF"); // SecondF
            mTransaction.addToBackStack(null);  // this is required to move to the previous fragment
            mTransaction.commit();
            commListener.PlaceName(data1,data2);  //passing value to activity
            break;

    }

}
interface CommBridge{

    void PlaceName(String data1,String data2);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context){
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof CommBridge){
        commListener= (CommBridge) context;
    }
}
```

}

**A**

```
 @Override
public void PlaceName(String data1, String data2) {
    SFragment sFragment=(SFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("SecondF");
    if (sFragment != null && sFragment.isInLayout()){
        Log.d("STATE","1");
        sFragment.setPlace(data1,data2);
    }else{
        Log.d("STATE","2");  // this is always  the case
    }
```

**F2**

```
public class SFragment extends Fragment {
String Place2,Place1;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.form_fragment2,container,false);
    return v;
}

void setPlace(String data1, String data2){
    place1 = data1;
    place2 =  data2;

}
}
```

Comment: you should use `Bundle` to send data from one fragment to another fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend putting the code for replacing the fragment in your Activity and put the values which should be passed to `SFragment()` in its arguments directly:

```
SFragment newFragment = new SFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("place1", data1);
args.putString("place2", data1);
newFragment.setArguments(args);
```

You could get them in `SFragment#onCreateView()`

```
String place1 = getArguments().getString("place1");
```

Also have a look here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: This solved my problem Marius. But why you recommended me to put the replacing code in Activity?Also Isn't it the case of direct communication between fragments which should be avoided?

Comment: The Activity should be in control and manage it's Fragments. The specific Fragment should literally not know that there's another Fragment. Then when you want to replace a Fragment, you only have to touch the controlling Activity and not search in every Fragment.

Comment: In my understanding direct communication is only if you try to call methods of a Fragment from another Fragment. Passing arguments over the controlling Activity is the common way to communicate.

Answer (score 2):

Let the activity be responsible for handling the onClick event of the Fragment. See the example below.

**Activity:**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Fragment1.CommBridge {


    private Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();
    private Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content, fragment1)
                .commit();


    }

    @Override
    public void onButtonClicked(String data1, String data2) {
        fragment2.setData(data1, data2);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content, fragment2)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

**Fragment1:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    interface CommBridge {
        void onButtonClicked(String data1, String data2);
    }

    private CommBridge handler;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof CommBridge) {
            handler = (CommBridge) context;
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                handler.onButtonClicked("Data1", "Data2");
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

**Fragment2**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

    private String data1;
    private String data2;

    public void setData(String data1, String data2) {
        this.data1 = data1;
        this.data2 = data2;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);

        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(data1 + "\n" + data2);

        return view;
    }
}
```